# How to get deviceToken of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I have registered my device (iPhone 4s, not a simulator) for push notifications from Parse. This was done successfully, as the pop-up appeared asking me if I would like to register my device for push notifications appeared.

However, when I hit Accept, I had forgotten the code which registers my `deviceToken` in the `PFInstallation` data which is stored on the server. Now, whenever I call `[application registerForRemoteNotifications];` in the `AppDelegate.m` method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, the method which produces the `deviceToken`, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`, is not called.

How can I call this method, and get my `deviceToken` on the database? Also, will push notifications work without the `deviceToken`? I have tried sending global push notifications, but then are not received by my iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting my app using the instructions here: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-clean-ios-junk-files-cache-3609079/ (instructions for "How to clean out your iPhone's memory: Remove file data"). When I got to the menu with different apps, I found my app, clicked it, then clicked "Delete app". This totally removes your app from your phone, so when you reinstall it, it can run the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this snippet to -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Enable Push Notifications

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        //ios8 ++
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
        {
            UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ios7
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have code similar to this which is called before [application registerForRemoteNotifications]; . Nevertheless, I used your code instead, and then in addition to my code, before calling [application registerForRemoteNotifications];, but didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: was still not called, unfortunately.